# How to get parent html element from child

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I have created a child.jsp file which has a button named Continue. I have created a jsp page named login.jsp which has name and password input text. and in that jsp file i have included child.jsp file using following code. I have created onclick listener in child.jsp file. I want to access the value of input field (name and password). How can i achieve this?

```
<jsp:include page="child.jsp" flush="true">  
                <jsp:param name="BtnName" value="Continue"/>  
                <jsp:param name="BtnContinue" value="Get Weather1"/>  
            </jsp:include>
```

Comment: If your question is about client side JavaScript, then please show us the client side code and not just the JSP that generates it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, using `window.parent.document` we can get the document of the parent.
Use the following code to get any element of parent using its id.

```
window.parent.document.getElementById("elementId");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you about JavaScript access, than better to use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) JavaScript framework and it's [Child Selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/).

```
    /**
     * Find parent form object for HTML DOM element.
     *
     * @return <HTMLFormElement>
     */
    $.fn.parentForm = function() {
        var object = this;
        while (object.tagName() != "FORM") {
            object = object.parent();
        }

        return object;
    }
```

Comment: But how to get parent form element from child?

Comment: Look at changes in my answer.

Comment: And where is the jQuery tag? Why reinvent closest?

Comment: You can do it without jQuery. I have recommended jQuery at first. But if you want simply get parent form - that's a decision on JavaScript.